# Show g is not surjective

Tags: analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

$\begin{align} f: A \rightarrow B, \space  g : B \rightarrow A, \end{align} $ and $\begin{align} f \circ g : B \rightarrow B \end{align}$ is bijective

I am not sure how to show that $g$ doesnt have to be surjective. Since $ f \circ g $ is bijective, by definition it is surjective, thus $\exists x\in B$ such that $\forall y \in B, \space f\circ g(x) = y $

$\begin{align} f\circ g(x) = y \\ f(g(x)) = y\end{align} $

and since $g$ has the same domain as $f\circ g$, then $\exists x\in B$ such that $\forall y \in A, \space g(x) = y $

I seem to be lost on how it is possible for g to not be surjective here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try what happens if $B$ has only one element but $A$ has more than one element.

Comment: well if there were only one element in B, say x1, f(x1) = y1, so for all y in A, f(x1) =/ y, hence not surjective?

Comment: More simply, note that $g:B\to A$ maps a one element set to a set with *more* than one element, and so cannot be onto (also known as surjective) for "cardinality reasons".

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help